# Is restriction of a function necessarily limited to a subset of the domain?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

A pretty basic question but I cannot find it either here or on the net.

The usual definition of restriction of a function $f : X \to Y$, to a set $X'$ (denoted by $f{\restriction_{X'}}$) assumes that $X' \subset X$, i.e. **the restricted domain is a subset of the original domain**. See for example the [Wikipedia definition of restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)#Formal_definition).

However, in certain contexts it may be simpler and very natural to extend this concept to any set $X'$, simply by considering $X \cap X'$; thus writing $f{\restriction_{X'}}$ directly instead of $f{\restriction_{X' \cap X}}$, because:

- the intent is clear even if $X'$ is **not** a subset of the domain;
- it saves some characters;
- if the domain of the function has no established name, than this operation requires even more characters, (something like $f{\restriction_{X'  \cap {\operatorname {dom} f} }}$);
- if the function is constructed as an expression (like $g\circ h$), then this becomes even more complex and requires unnecessary repetition
  $(g \circ h){\restriction_{X' \cap \operatorname {dom}(g \circ h) }}$ .

Naturally, if such expressions become abundant, it is possible to add a short remark on the extended usage. However, I am still curious whether

- such extension would be considered (even a minor) abuse of notation without any remark?
- there is some deeper reason why the "usual" definition assumes that the restriction is limited to subsets of the domain? This constraint seems completely unnecessary.

Note:

Despite using the "usual" definition, even the Wikipedia article hints at the possibility of the "extended" one:

> Informally, the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is the same function as $f$, but is only defined on  $\displaystyle A\cap \operatorname {dom} f$.

because if we had really assumed $A \subset \operatorname {dom} f$ then it would have been enough to write "... but is only defined on $A$".

Comment: Not sure about the answer, I never used restriction to a non-subset of the domain, but: $\operatorname {dom}(g \circ h)=\operatorname {dom}(h)$,

Comment: Actually on second thought I did use  restriction to a non-subset of the domain, I just defined $\overline{X}=X'\cap X$

Comment: You are right, the example is not perfect and can be simplified to $(g \circ h){\restriction_{X' \cap \operatorname {dom} (h) }}$. Nevertheless, this version still repeats $h$ and the intent is somewhat less clear (to me at least)

Comment: And this was just an example, not to be considered the main reason for my question, which is rather theoretical.

Comment: The suggested workaround, $f {\restriction_\overline{X'}}$ with defining  $\overline{X'}=X'\cap X$ is a good idea. However, it assumes that $X$ is already defined and fixed in the context.

Comment: The point is; you can set the domain of $f$ to be whatever you want, so set $X=\mbox{dom}(f)$ at the start

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function and $X'$ be a set. Define the *restriction* of $f$ to $X'$ as $f\restriction_{X'}=\{(x,y)\in f:x\in X'\}$.

You'll find that it agrees with the usual definition whenever $X'\subseteq X$. Else, $X'\nsubseteq X$ and you'll find that $f\restriction_{X'}=f\restriction_{X'\cap X}$. FWIW I prefer my definition as the usual one is unnecessarily restrictive, and as you said, shortens notation.

Comment: So this answer says that (1) no abuse occurs and (2) there is no reason why all sources assume $X' \subset X$, if I understand correctly. I am still a bit unsure about (2). This obvious and easy definition makes me more an more puzzled as to why alll sources I have ever seen use the "unnecessary" (?) constraint.

Comment: Because most of the time, the set $X'$ being restricted to is in fact a subset of $X$.